# Can't access internet after installing vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, bigdata

I was following this new edx course on *Big data on Apache spark*. For setting up environment I was told to install **virtual-box** and **vagrant**. After installing box and vagrant I restarted my laptop. My modem was working fine, Windows was showing Ethernet connection active but when I try to open any browser and search it was reported that **can't connect to internet**. I tried uninstalling both box and vagrant but no use. I even restored my system to state when these both applications were not installed but still I can't access internet. What should I do? I'm using Windows  8.1

Answer (score 2):

Just googled a bit and found this:

http://thomascgreen.com/tech/?p=26

Seems to be a working solution.

> In any case this is how I got it working again. First go to:
>
> Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings
>
> Right click on the connection you are having a problem with. In my
>   case it was “Wireless Network Connection”. On this menu select
>   “Properties”.
>
> [image]
>
> Notice there is a line here that says “Virtual Box Bridged Networking
>   Driver”. This is Vagrant watching the connection, is my guess.
>
> When I unchecked the box in front of “Virtual Box Bridged Networking
>   Driver” my internet connection started working again.
>
> Now at this point I started using Google to find out what was going
>   on. I never found a solution or reason. After searching I rechecked
>   the box. And everything started working again.

I would also advice to disable/enable all network cards, from the "network connections" panel. (right click on the networks, open the "Network center" and then go to to "update parameters" (I don't have the exact english labels, my Windows isn't in English). It may fix the issue.

Comment: Vadorequest as I have already mentioned that I uninstalled  box and vagrant so I didn't found any "virtual box bridged driver".

Comment: Did you try to disable/enable all you network cards?

Comment: Yes I did but still no success!

Comment: Maybe you should try reinstalling it and apply the solution explained above.

Comment: Vadorequest I reinstalled it and did followed every step but still no use. I later tried to ping Google and the reply was normal as it has to be. But from browsers still I'm unable to browse.

Comment: Don't you have a proxy configured somehow? Try to open it by typing "proxy" using Windows button. Then "configure proxy server" then "connexions" tab, then "networks parameters" button on the bottom.